# python pandas: remove part of date time object (datetime64[ns])

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe , and I am trying to remove the day and time part of a date time column (i.e. only keep the year and month part). I did the following:

```
df['my_date_new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['my_date'].dt.year, df['my_date'].dt.month, 0)
```

but got the following error: `TypeError: invalid type comparison`

What did I do wrong here and how could I fix this?

Comment: When you say remove, do you mean you just want a string? Period representing the Month?  Or a date that is the end/beginning of the Month?

Comment: If one of the below solutions solved your problem, please consider accepting (green tick on left), or feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the example `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(my_date=pd.date_range('now', periods=4, freq='15D')))

df

                     my_date
0 2018-04-16 10:39:16.218988
1 2018-05-01 10:39:16.218988
2 2018-05-16 10:39:16.218988
3 2018-05-31 10:39:16.218988
```

Here are some examples

```
df.assign(
    Period=df.my_date.dt.to_period('M'),
    String=df.my_date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m'),
    NewDate=pd.to_datetime(df.my_date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-01'))
)

                     my_date  Period   String    NewDate
0 2018-04-16 10:39:16.218988 2018-04  2018-04 2018-04-01
1 2018-05-01 10:39:16.218988 2018-05  2018-05 2018-05-01
2 2018-05-16 10:39:16.218988 2018-05  2018-05 2018-05-01
3 2018-05-31 10:39:16.218988 2018-05  2018-05 2018-05-01
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You cannot remove the day and time from a `datetime` object.

You can reset them, for example to day = 1, or time = 0, but you cannot *remove* them.

Just like in real life.

---

What you *can* do is reset your day to 1 and time to 00:00:00. Thus `datetime` object inputs with the same year and month are modified so that they align.

Data from @piRSquared.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(my_date=pd.date_range('now', periods=4, freq='15D')))

print(df)

#                      my_date
# 0 2018-04-16 22:27:47.373127
# 1 2018-05-01 22:27:47.373127
# 2 2018-05-16 22:27:47.373127
# 3 2018-05-31 22:27:47.373127

df['my_date'] = df['my_date'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=1)).dt.normalize()

print(df)

#      my_date
# 0 2018-04-01
# 1 2018-05-01
# 2 2018-05-01
# 3 2018-05-01
```

Comment: But you can set them to `0` or `1` to make `2018-04-16 10:30:00.000000` the same as `2018-04-01 12:15:00.000000`, effectively removing the information from the day and time areas.  \

Comment: But they aren't removed at all. Just normalized. You can't *remove* these properties.

Comment: But your answer isn't helpful.  Simply saying, "it isn't possible" when OP doesn't need something done that isn't possible isn't helpful.  He/she needs a way to normalize the datetime object.  Consider @piRSquared 's comment

Comment: @ChootsMagoots, Fair enough, I was hoping for OP to reword his question. As it stands, I'm uncomfortable with this Q&A at the Q part.

Comment: I don't disagree.  This is the kind of question that already has been asked 12 times on stackoverflow in slightly different formats.  IMO it's best to either choose to be helpful or mark it as a duplicate and move on.

Comment: @ChootsMagoots, Fair point, i'll keep in mind for future. I also updated my answer to be (hopefully) more helpful.